# Parallel translation along a self intersecting curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $c:I\to M$ be a self-intersecting on manifold $M$. How can one define the parallel translation of the tangent vector $\dot{c}(t_0)$ along $c$? Is the parallel translation along $c$ well-defined??

How should one define the tangent vector field along a self-intersecting curve?

Is there any book which can help me?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why is it not well-defined?

Comment: Because there are two tangent vector $\dot{c}(t_1)$ and $\dot{c}(t_1)$ in the intersection point $p=c(t_1) =c(t_2)$.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The definition still goes through.